# Proving there's no $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n^2 = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

I feel that my attempt is not what is expected in a Real Analysis course and that there's something I should incorporate from the Algebraic properties of Real numbers. My hunch is that there's better proof with induction, but was not able to think of any and could be wrong.

**My attempt:**

$$n^2 = 2 $$
$$n^2 = 1 + 1 $$
$$n^2+(-1)=1+1+(-1) $$
$$n^2-1=1+(1+(-1)) $$
$$n^2-1=1$$
Case $n=0$: then $-1=1$

Case $n \neq 0$: then $n^2 \geq 1$ and $n^2-1 \neq 1$

Comment: In the case that $n \ne 0$, how did you use $n^2 \ge 1$ to deduce that $n^2-1 \ne 1$?

Comment: Alternatively notice $1^2<2<(1+1)^2$ and so $2$ cannot be a square as it is strictly between two consecutive squares

Comment: You could also go ahead and use the standard proof that the square root of 2 is irrational, and thus is not an integer as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Well done!

Minor pet peeve: You are clearly trying to prove by contradiction. It would be nice to write $$"\text{suppose that there exists a positive integer } n \text{ such that }n^2=2"$$

Then conclude that you get a contradiction.

---

You could have also proved by checking just one case. Clearly the square root of $2$ is less than $2$. Thus, if there did exist a positive integer less than $2$ whose square equals $2$, the only possibility is $1$. But since $1^2=1$, we conclude that there does not exist any such integer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Since $~n^2 = (-n)^2,~$ and $~0^2 \neq 2,~$ it is sufficient to prove the assertion for $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$.

Further, for $x \in \Bbb{R^+},$ if $~f(x) = x^2,~$ then $f'(x) = 2x > 0.$

Therefore, $~f(x)~$ is a strictly increasing function, for $x \in \Bbb{R^+}.$

Therefore, for $~x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb{R^+},~: ~x_1 \neq x_2,~$ you have that

$$x_1 < x_2 \iff x_1^2 < x_2^2.$$

Based on the above analysis, the problem is immediately resolved by noting that $1^2 < 2 < 2^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Using the algebraic properties of the integers,  you can adapt the standard rational argument in this simpler case as well

Since $2$ is prime, we have $2|2=n^2$,  thus $2|n$.   So dividing by 2 gets us $n \cdot \frac n 2=1$, the product of two integers is 1 means they are units.  The only units in the integers are $1$ and $-1$, which both square to 1, so we're done

Answer (score 0):

$(-n)^2=n^2$ so we can restrict ourselves to $n\ge 0$

For $n\le 1$ then multiplying by $n$ we get $n^2\le n\le 1$

For $n\ge 2$ then multiplying by $n$ we get $n^2\ge 2n\ge 4$

Therefore neither $n^2=2$ nor $n^2=3$ are reachable.